# publisher-subcriber communication is stable?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made 2 ROS node. One is for publishing and the other is for subscribing.
However, sometimes receiving callback function is not called , even though a message is published.

Is the communication in publisher-subscriber is guaranteed?

Also, which kind of communication model is recommended when there are only 1 publisher and only 1 subscriber?(one-to-one)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243847/publisher-subcriber-communication-is-stable?/) by [demi H](https://answers.ros.org/users/27765/demi-h/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The connection between a publisher and its subscribers should work. It may drop messages if the queues become full, but otherwise you should see reliable message transport. If you're seeing something other than the occasional dropped message, there's probably some kind of issue with your configuration.

Random failures are almost never random; the first step to troubleshooting this is to figure out which conditions reliably cause the issue you're seeing.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0